# Freebase Log in Python

Tags: python, authentication, freebase

I am new to freebase. Might be a simple answer but I cant seem to understand the freebase API. I try to run a simple query using the command `queryResult = freebase.mqlread(queryFB);` and I get the error below. I haven't logged in to the API. I created an account which is a google account. My question is when I call `freebase.login(username,password);` what do I use? Google account details? I am also attaching my query.

Query:

```
{
    "type": "/food/dish",
    "id": dish,
    "name": None,
    "cuisine": 
    [{
        "id": None,
        "name": None,
        "region_of_origin": 
        [{
            "id": None,
            "name": None,
            "/location/location/contains": 
            [{
                "id": None,
                "name": city,
                "type": "/location/citytown",
                "limit": 20
            }]
        }],
        "optional": "optional"
    }],
    "type_of_dish1": 
    [{
        "id": None,
        "name": None,
        "optional": "optional"
    }]
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error": 
    {
    "errors": 
    [
        {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "userRateLimitExceededUnreg",
            "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
            "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using an obsolete client library and/or API.  The current API doesn't use a username/password pair, but rather an API key.

Comment: Thanks! if you don't mind can you let me know how to add the API I got from google to the freebase login()? example would help. I should get the new API if i type `ez_seutp freebase`

Comment: As far as I know, they never updated the Freebase Python library.  You'll need to either use the generic Python library for Google APIs or roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will explain how to use api key for running MQL. You will need to get only the apikey for freebase. NO username or password is required.

https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview